# Pentaho Rest Client Post Step

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Does anyone have an example of using the post method in Pentaho? I am trying to formulate the body, but I keep getting a 415 error.

When I try the get method, I don't have any issues, it's only for post.

```
Generate Rows Step:
Name      type       Value
body      string     {'filterGroups':[{'filters': [{'propertyName': 'closedate', 'value': 2024-02-11, 'operator': 'LT'}]}]}
```

Any suggestions?